# How to get current year in ABAP CDS view

Tags: abap, cds

Is there any way to get current timestamp or current date ?  SQL syntax is `date.now()` but it doesn't work in ABAP CDS. Is there any solution without parameters ?

Comment: Just to make sure: You don´t want to use sy-datum / $session.system_date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 7.50 you have `tstmp_current_utctimestamp()`. It may be used to compare with other timestamps, leading to a need to convert typical date and time fields. Example:

```
// As our system is set to UTC already, these cast and calculation are OK awaiting ABAP 7.51. Add a day if time is 24:00.
case resb.bdztp when '240000' 
                then cast( cast( cast( concat( DATS_ADD_DAYS( resb.bdter, 1, 'NULL'), '000000' ) as abap.numc(14) ) as abap.dec( 15, 0 ) ) as timestamp )
                else cast( cast( cast( concat( resb.bdter, resb.bdztp )                          as abap.numc(14) ) as abap.dec( 15, 0 ) ) as timestamp )
end as RequirementDateTimeUTC,
```

Consumption:

```
// Seconds since Requirement Date & Time for view isOverdue. 
tstmp_seconds_between( resb.RequirementDateTimeUTC, tstmp_current_utctimestamp(), 'NULL') as SecondsSinceReqDateTimeUTC,
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I can harldy image figuring out such a casting concatenation cascade on my own. Did you find these workarounds/hacks in an official documentation or did you develop using trial and error?

Comment: thanks for that. but my abap 7.40 :( is that any solition for 7.40 ? or hard to upgrade for 7.50 ?

Comment: @konstantin: Inspiration for the cast from here: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/11/cds-view-add-days-to-date/

Comment: @Mert: For 7.40, I'm not aware of any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The session variable `$session.system_date` is used in a CDS view to provide direct access to the current system date.

There is not yet a session variable for the current system time and a CDS view can be given an appropriate input parameter instead. The special annotation `@Environment.systemField` makes it possible to pass the value of the ABAP system field **sy-uzeit** to a parameter of this type.

[Source](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abencds_f1_date_time_functions.htm)

Comment: Please carefully check your ABAP version. There have been quite a lot of changes in the CDS between [7.50](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-us/abencds_f1_date_time_functions.htm) and 7.51. For example using the current datetime in `WHERE` clauses or `JOIN` conditions is not possible in ABAP 7.50.

Comment: @konstantin, what's wrong with this answer? It's OK. Session variables haven't changed since 7.50 to 7.51 and neither OP nor answerer didn't mention the need of`WHERE`/`JOIN`. Don't fabricate additional restrictions for simple question

Comment: @Suncatcher : In my case using `$session.system_date` in the SELECT list results in an "ABAP Activation problem"  during activation of the CDS definition in ABAP 7.50: "Unexpected word '$session.system_date'" I can only use a workaround and inject it as a parameter: `with parameters @Environment.systemField : #SYSTEM_DATE p_datum : syst_datum` (with a lot of performance side effects). See also [ABAP News for Release 7.51 – Date and Time in ABAP CDS and Open SQL](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/04/abap-news-for-release-7.51-date-and-time-in-abap-cds-and-open-sql/) by Horst Keller.

Comment: See also [this answer by Horst Keller on the exact same question](https://answers.sap.com/answers/12547821/view.html):

_"Up to Release 7.50, there is no session variable for the system date in ABAP CDS. This will only come with an upcoming release (7.51). Before 7.51, you can use a parameter for that. See the discussion Current date in ABAP CDS views | SCN. If you are working on 7.51 already, use $session.system_date."_

Comment: Yes, the date variable appeared in the 7.51, but as the version is not specified explicitly in the question, the answers should be version-agnostic and suggest all-versions solutions. So this answer is perfectly valid if anybody find this question further